# Обработка исключений при загрузке файла

Tags: c#

Качаю много видео файлов с помощью WebClient.DownloadFileAsync. Время от времени сервер разрывает подключение. И webClient рапортует об ошибке.
О том что произошла ошибка я узнаю только в событии DownloadComleted. Как мне перезапустить загрузку именно этого файла? 
Мне почему-то не удалось нормально передать в евент свой объект. Может подскажете как это сделать?

Comment: (1) Ну используйте перегрузку с userToken, передайте туда что-нибудь, получите это назад в аргументах DownloadCompleted, (2) А почему не DownloadFileTaskAsync? Там всё будет проще, никаких ивентов.

Comment: Пробовал сначала таск, но там была какая-то непонятка. Таск зависал ничего не качая и не возвращая ошибку. Уже не помню, что писал. 
Попробую с userToken. Спасибо!

Comment: Попробовал! Это то что надо. Не могу все запомнить, что userToken передается в userState. Все время пытаюсь найти где задать userState)

Comment: Отлично :) Тогда позже оформлю как ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам пригодится перегрузка [`WebClient.DownloadFileAsync (Uri, String, Object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms144197(v=vs.110).aspx), принимающая `userToken`. Для этой перегрузки `userToken` возвращается по событию `DownloadFileCompleted` в `AsyncCompletedEventArgs` как [`UserState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.userstate(v=vs.110).aspx).

Таким образом, вы сможете идентифицировать вашу загрузку.

Comment: Для всех кто забывает, что userState==userToken. И постоянно ищет где указать UserState.
(Надеюсь, я не один такой)